# loop through implicit array

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I've been stuck on this for awhile now. I'm trying to loop through this array so I can perform some calculations but I cannot figure out how to loop through there values. Any suggestions?

I managed to figure out how to get there collection structures but I want to loop through each structure and grab there values as well and thats what I'm stuck on.

Also, I want to refrain from using cfscript if possible as I'm still in the learning stages of learning coldfusion.

Here is my code:

```
<cfset houseStuff = {
    Bedroom = [
        'Luxury Duvet Set with Alternative Down Comforter',
        'Accent Coverlet & Shams',
        'Two Sets of Luxurious Liens',
        'Mattress Pad',
        'Blanket',
        'Six Bed Pillows',
        'Clock Radio',
        'Twenty Hangers'
    ],
    Bathroom = [
        'Four Bath Towels',
        'Four Hand Towels',
        'Four Face Towels',
        'Bath Rug',
        'Shower Curtain',
        'Stainless Tooth Brush Holder & Soap Dish',
        'Wastebasket',
        'Artwork',
        'Hair Dryer',
        'Toilet Brush & Plunger'
    ],
    Dining = [
        'Dinnerware',
        'Place Mats',
        'Napkins',
        'Flatware',
        'Glassware & Wine Glasses'
    ],
    Kitchen = [
        'Microwave',
        'Cookware',
        'Mixing Bowls',
        'Baking Dish',
        'Colander',
        'Stainless Utensil Holder',
        'Large Fork',
        'Large Spoon',
        'Spatula',
        'Whisk',
        'Measuring Spoon & Cup',
        'Carving & Paring Knives',
        'Four Steak Knives',
        'Cutting Board',
        'Salt & Pepper Set',
        'Wine Opener',
        'Coffee Maker',
        'Toaster',
        'Electric Can Opener',
        'Flatware Tray',
        'Kitchen Wastebasket',
        'Dish Towels',
        'Pot Holders',
        'Pitcher',
        '10" Non-Stick Frying Pan',
        'Cookie Sheet',
        'Stainless Steel Electric Tea Kettle',
        '3 Piece Non-Metal (Spatula, Spoon, Paste Spoon) Combo'
    ],
    Micellaneous = [
        'Iron & Cutting Board',
        'Cordless Dual Phone with Digital Answering Machine',
        'Broom',
        'Dust Pan',
        'Vacuum',
        'Decor',
        'Laundry Basket'
    ],
    StarterKit = [
        'Bath Tissue',
        'Soap',
        'Shampoo & Conditioner',
        'Paper Towels',
        'Sponge',
        'Laundry Soap',
        'Dishwasher Detergent',
        'Liquid Dish Soap',
        'Extra Light Bulbs',
        'Coffee',
        'Sugar',
        'Creamer',
        'Bottled Water',
        'Oatmeal',
        'Breakfast Bars',
        'Peanuts',
        'Chips',
        'Mints',
        'Welcome Information'
    ],
    MasterBedroom = [
        'Queen bed',
        'Headboard',
        'Two Nightstands',
        'Dresser & Mirrior',
        'Two Lamps',
        'Artwork',
        'LCD Television'
    ],
    LivingRoom = [
        'Sofa',
        'Chair',
        'End Table',
        'Coffee Table',
        'Lamp',
        'LCD TV w/stand',
        'DVD Player',
        'Artwork'
    ],
    DiningRoom = [
        'Dining Table',
        'Dining Chairs',
        'Artwork'
    ],
    OfficePackage = [
        'Desk',
        'Chair',
        'Lamp'
    ],
    AdditionalBedrooms = [
        'Queen or Two Twin Beds',
        'Headboard',
        'Nightstand',
        'Chest of Drawers',
        'Lamp',
        'Artwork'
    ]
} />

<cfloop collection="#houseStuff#" item="key">
    <cfdump var="#key#"> <br>
    <!--- <p style="color:##fff;">#key#:</p> <br /> --->
</cfloop>
```

Comment: What version of ColdFusion? If you're learning, I'd stick with the newer versions. There's a good bit of difference between CF9 or less and the versions above CF10. And a fair bit of difference between CF10 and CF2016.

Comment: Dumped out the Server variable. I'm using 9.

Comment: Is CF9 for work or for learning? If for work, then your kinda stuck, but pay attention to the version you learn. You'll see a lot of learning info for CF10+ (and I think learncfinaweek.com is CF10), but there were quite a few changes between 9 and 10. Many things got easier to do after 10. If it's just for learning, I'd bump up to a higher version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you'd prefer tags instead of script, but if you are in the learning stages of ColdFusion, I'd still recommend learning how to properly use `cfscript`. In addition to making your CF a little bit cleaner, it will also make your life a lot easier, especially for things like looping.

Outputting all elements becomes:

```
<cfscript>
for ( i in houseStuff ) { // loop over the outer Structure
    writeOutput(i & ":<br>") ;
    for ( j in houseStuff[i] ) { // loop over each inner Array key
        writeOutput(j & "<br>") ;
    }
    writeOutput("<br>");
}
</cfscript>
```

https://trycf.com/gist/898988f6969a57aa5dece39c42037cfd/acf?theme=monokai

... which, in this context, does get into the philosophical discussion of whether to write output code in tags or script and goes slightly beyond the scope of this question. But I've always been a proponent of learning best-practices at the same time as the basics. Personally, I do tend to follow the tags-for-output view, but for basic looping, the script version is a bit cleaner to me. I'd learn both.

Also check out: http://www.learncfinaweek.com. There's a section in there on Looping with both methods.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I appreciate it. `cfscript` looks very similar to how JavaScript is written and I have the basics of it down so I'll make sure to try to get into cfscript in the future. It's just I'm trying to focus in on what I know until I get more comfortable.

Comment: @Curious13 `cfscript` is very similar to `javascript`. That's one of the things that makes it nice.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, I finally figured it out. I had to loop through the collection first. Once I do that create another loop inside it to loop over it's structured values.

```
<cfloop collection="houseStuff" item="key">
   <!---<cfdump var="#houseStuff[key]"> --->
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(houseStuff[key])#" index="j">
        #j#
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Unless you specifically need the position, an "array" loop is a little simpler: `<cfloop array="#arr#" index="elem"><cfdump var="#elem#></cfloop>`

Comment: My vote put your reputation into triple digits.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: @Ageax Note: In this situation, the array loop won't work. This is a structure of arrays, not an array of arrays.

Comment: I didn't realize that ColdFusion 7 supported the syntax in your question.  But it does not support array loops.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I just dumped out the Server and it says I'm running 9. However, when I tried the cfloop it broke the page. It returned that it doesn't support the attribute of array in the loop and gave me a list of supported attributes for `cfloop`. I'll look into more of this in the future.

Comment: @Shawn - Not solely an array loop, no. It can be used for the inner loop, instead of the from/to loop shown above. That is assuming it is supported in their version. Requires CF9+, maybe update 1?

Comment: @Curious13 - You must be running an old version. Works with 9.0.2.

Comment: `cfloop array=""` was added in CF8, but I think it was wonky until 9.0.1. Can't remember. The error may be from using it in the outer loop. The outer loop would stay `collection`, where the inner loop would be `array`.

Comment: I'm using 9,0,0,251028

Comment: I don't have 9. I may have been thinking of the cfscript that was added in CF9. If Shawn's right about cfloop being added in CF8, then it should work.  https://trycf.com/gist/19ed4d7266e41de9a6f6adb3b25933df/acf?theme=monokai

Comment: `array=""` was added to `cfloop` in 8. `cfloop` has been in CF as long as I can remember. It may be breaking if you're trying to do an array loop around `housestuff`. It won't work because that's a structure and not an array.

Comment: @Curious13 RE: "9,0,0,251028" >> If possible, you should patch up to at least 9.0.1, which should get you up to Java 7. 9.0.2 would be a little bit better, but it will remove Verity and replace it with SOLR. There are a few other things to watch out for: http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2013/8/19/understanding_ColdFusion_9.0.2_a_FAQ. Again, is CF9 a Production system, or is it just for learning? Or is it for learning for a Production system?

Comment: And this: https://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2015/08_w35/931150/coldfusion-comparison.pdf

Comment: It's a production system with a lot of sensitive data in it. I didn't set up the system the past developer did who specialized in ColdFusion on both the language and setting up the server itself. I think while he was here ColdFusion 9 was the current version. If I were to upgrade the production system which is using IIS as the webserver, I'm afraid I'll do more harm than good. We have a Dev sandbox but I'll need to do more research before upgrading the version.

Comment: @Curious13 If it's already a Prod system, and you're learning CF to support it, keep in mind that most of the learning stuff you'll come across will likely be CF10. There are quite a few difference between CF9 and later versions. It will be enough to make you wish you could do some of the things in 9 that you learn about in 10. :-/